# Empty variable after UIPickerView didSelectRow

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I'm new to Swift.

I try to read some JSON Data from WebAPI after the row is selected. Everything works fine except one thing. I don't know why the variable `DaneSkladu_array` is empty outside the `URLSession` part (last print). Could you tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    
    let WybranySklad = NrExact_array[row].prefix(6)
    lbl_NumerSkladu.text = String(WybranySklad)
    
    //self.customerPV.reloadAllComponents()
    let url = URL(string: "https://...")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([CustomerData].self, from: data)
            for klient in json{
                self.DaneSkladu_array.append(klient.KrotkaNazwa)
                if(klient.Nr_Exact == String(WybranySklad))
                {
                    
                }
            }
        } catch let jsonError {
            print ("Blad json: ", jsonError)
        }
     
    }.resume()

    print(self.DaneSkladu_array.count)
}
```

Comment: `print(self.DaneSkladu_array.count)` is executed before the data is loaded because the `URLSession.shared.dataTask(...).resume()` creates an asynchronous task and immediately returns control to the current queue, without waiting for the download to complete over the network.

Comment: Ok, thx. Can you give me some hint how can I catch this data ?

Comment: I found DispatchQueue.main.async {}, works for me, thanks for explanations how it works!!

Answer (score 0):

```
let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([CustomerData].self, from: data)
        for klient in json{
            self.DaneSkladu_array.append(klient.KrotkaNazwa)
            // print(self.DaneSkladu_array.count) // place print statement here if you want to see the number of items after every new client inserted
        }
        print(self.DaneSkladu_array.count) // Print just the total amound of clients after inserting them all
  ...
```